# C# MVC with jQuery Datatables: Retrieving variables from GET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatables

This is the query string that Datatables.net sends to my MVC action:

> ?sEcho=8&iColumns=6&sColumns=&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=10&mDataProp_0=HomeCountry&mDataProp_1=HostCountry&mDataProp_2=YearOneRate&mDataProp_3=YearOtherRate&mDataProp_4=RateType&mDataProp_5=Controls&sSearch=&bRegex=false&sSearch_0=&bRegex_0=false&bSearchable_0=true&sSearch_1=&bRegex_1=false&bSearchable_1=true&sSearch_2=&bRegex_2=false&bSearchable_2=true&sSearch_3=&bRegex_3=false&bSearchable_3=true&sSearch_4=&bRegex_4=false&bSearchable_4=true&sSearch_5=&bRegex_5=false&bSearchable_5=true&iSortCol_0=1&sSortDir_0=asc&iSortingCols=1&bSortable_0=true&bSortable_1=true&bSortable_2=true&bSortable_3=true&bSortable_4=true&bSortable_5=false&_=1391446190711

This is my controller action header in MVC:

```
public JsonResult GetData(int sEcho, int iDisplayStart, int iDisplayLength, string sSearch)
```

My question is: How do I get variables such as these (?):

> bSortable_0=true&bSortable_1=true&bSortable_2=true&bSortable_3=true&bSortable_4=true&bSortable_5=false

Notice how the number after `bSortable_` could be anything from 0 to 5 or more.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part), I found it very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for that, it led me to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse querystring -

```
NameValueCollection queryCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query);
var items = queryCollection
                 .AllKeys
                 .SelectMany(queryCollection.GetValues, (k, v) => new { key = k, value = v })
                 .Where(p => p.key.Contains("bSortable"))
                 .ToList();
```

And the output -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the query string parameters from the `Request.QueryString` collection, including the ones you didn't make method parameters. You can find the individual keys in `Request.QueryString.Keys`. Using that, you could loop through the collection and grab each key/value pair.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple other ways. You could do:

```
string bSearchable0 = Request["bSearchable_0"];
```

Or you could make a class and have your action method take it as a parameter:

```
public class jQueryDataTableParam
{
    public int sEcho { get; set; }
    public int iDisplayStart { get; set; } 
    public int iDisplayLength { get; set; } 
    public string sSearch { get; set; }
    public bool bSearchable_1 { get; set; }
    public bool bSortable_1 { get; set; }
    //....
}
```

Using the above make your action method look more like

```
public JsonResult GetData(jQueryDataTableParam param)
```